# GCC : picking up wrong version of headers

Tags: gcc, llvm, clang, glibc

I downloaded and started to build LLVM / CLANG. I initially had gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48) installed but LLVM website stated to use a higher one. So I downloaded and compiled / build GCC gcc version 4.7.2 (GCC). Now I started to build LLVM after setting the below config:

```
# setenv PATH /usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib64:$PATH
# setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib/:/usr/local/lib64/
# setenv CC /usr/local/bin/gcc
```

Note the path where GCC 4.1.2 available is /usr/bin while that of 4.7.2 I found it in /usr/local/bin by default

But the LLVM build failed stating:

```
In file included from /x/home/satprasad/llvm/llvm-3.1.src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_posix.cc:35:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/algorithm:64:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:69:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/iosfwd:45:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++io.h:38:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr.h:132:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:100:1: error: weakref declaration must have
      internal linkage
__gthrw(pthread_once)
```

But it should pick files / headers for 4.7.2 versions not 4.1.2 ones - can you please let me know how to fix this - the line that gives error is in below file/code:

```
llvm-3.1.src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_posix.cc

#include <algorithm>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have problems with this as well, on CentOS.  Not exactly the same symptoms, but using gcc 4.7.2.  I gave up and downloaded the rpm's instead and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running:

```
./configure --help
```

shows this option:

```
--with-gcc-toolchain    Directory where gcc is installed.
```

So try:

```
--with-gcc-toolchain /usr/local
```

And don't set any environment variables.

Comment: I'd recommend to ask on the [LLVM mailing list](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/mailman/listinfo/llvmdev) then.

Comment: I did not get a full concrete option but installing latest GCC with DESTDIR=/usr or configuring with --prefix=/usr solved the issue. Note this way I am forced to have latest version of GCC only. Other way is mentioned in the link : http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#multiple but since for older one I do not have any code, binaries or RPMs I re-installed the latest one

Comment: @Prakash Well, you pretty much messed up your system now. You shouldn't install into /usr. That's reserved for software installed through the package manager. For example now you may get overwritten files by OS updates. And there's no real way to clean it up, since you can't uninstall manually installed software.